Multiple slashes replacement doesn't work in Apache
My .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Filter TRACE, TRACK and DEBUG request methods

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(DEBUG|TRACE|TRACK) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/{2,}
RewriteRule \/{2,} / [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php

When I navigate to /about////// I wanna redirect to /about/
Online .htaccess tester show is everything should work right, but no
Test form https://htaccess.madewithlove.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/{2,}
This condition was met.

RewriteRule \/{2,} / [R=302,L]
The new url is https://site.ru/about/
Test are stopped, a redirect will be made with status code 302

ANSWER
My solution

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
# Filter TRACE, TRACK and DEBUG request methods
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(DEBUG|TRACE|TRACK) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php


I am confused, the rule RewriteRule \/{2,} / [R=302,L] will certainly not redirect to /about/ ...

Apart from that I would like to make a small remark. Not meant to solve anything, but to address some issue I see quite frequently: this reads as if you are trying to somehow handle a symptom you observe. Usually it makes much more sense to cure the actual cause than to work on symptoms. Here that would mean to prevent handing out links that contain such doubled slashes. Where do those links come from? Who or what created them? How can that be stopped?

maybe \/{2,} also grabbs "http(s)://..." and replaces with "http(s)/..."?

@arkascha I need it for my college work, so that's the essence. I just gotta make this redirect

@DuesserBaest No, REQUEST_URI doen't give http and hostname
